# Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception in Python

Tags: python, cartopy

I want to use cartopy to make a diagram of data for EDA. But the result shows Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception with a diagram

[image]

Here is my code

```
# Understanding this code is not essential for the tutorial 

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

# Latitude and longitude for the edges of the map
lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2= 32, 42.5, -125, -114

# Create figures
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Mercator())

# Get latitude and longitude for each data point
x, y = (train['Longitude'].to_numpy(), train['Latitude'].to_numpy())

# Scatter plot as heat map
ax.scatter(x,y,s=(train['Population'].to_numpy()/30.0), c=train['MedianHouseValue'].to_numpy(), 
           edgecolors='none', cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'), alpha=0.5, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Add state borders and coast line
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('50m'))
ax.set_extent([-125, -113.5, 32, 42.5], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_title('Median house values in California (training data)', fontsize=17, y=1.01, fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! when asking about errors, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - it contains valuable debugging information that we (and you) need to be able to identify where the exception is being triggered.